# Ceramic crock pot - No cracks, but looks like coating is spotted. Can I fix it?

Tags: crockpot

I made beef stew in a crock pot for the first time, and didn't realize I shouldn't store the food in the ceramic pot.  No cracks, but looks like coating is spotted. Can I fix it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! You wouldn't happen to have a picture of the pot to share with us? Might help us come up with an idea or two...

Comment: Might be able to use CLR to clean it, but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want to use it afterwards for food... :p

Answer (score 1):

I found this question asked and answered in... *ahem* [a different forum.](http://www.reddit.com/r/slowcooking/comments/1srm4m/crock_pot_weird_stains_need_help_cleaning/) The gist is that they recommend letting it soak in white vinegar and warm water before scrubbing and it should come right off. A couple other posters recommended a product called [Bar Keepers Friend](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V72992) for cleaning.

Comment: You could probably use denture cleaner as well.  Toss a tablet or two in with some water and let it soak for a bit.  Anything ceramic based can be cleaned this way.